# Google Load Balancer HTTPS Mapping between wordpress.com and google storage bucket

Tags: reverse-proxy, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, rewrite

My question is about how to best route a particular URL to a static page while routing everything else to a wordpress.com site

I have a domain on Google domains, currently the A record for the bare domain points to IPs for wordpress.com site

I'd like to instead point to a load balancer/reverse proxy so that a particular URL (on the bare domain, not a subdomain) gets pointed to a static HTML page (in Google storage bucket or wherever is best), while everything else gets routed to the wordpress.com IPs.

How do I best do this in Google cloud?

Comment: HTTP(S) load balancer with url map that points to two different resources should do the trick. One will point to a bucket, another to your WP site.

Comment: Is [this](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets) what you are looking for? https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets

Comment: @AlexG, I looked at this but I am not sure how to balance between google bucket and external IP addresses based on incoming URL

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question right, once you completed the setup, it should automatically do the balancing on its own.

Comment: I don't see here how to send some traffic to bucket while other traffic to wordpress.com based on url. I understand how to setup load balancer + bucket alone.

Comment: It is also on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets#send-traffic) on my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

[A URL redirect redirects your domain's visitors from one URL to another.](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map#configuring_url_maps)

*You can add backend services and backend buckets to a URL map.*

**Before deploying a URL map, make sure you validate the URL map configuration to ensure that the map is routing requests to the appropriate backends as intended. You can do this by adding tests to the URL map configuration.**

Use the `gcloud compute url-maps validate` command to validate URL map configuration.

```
gcloud compute url-maps validate --source PATH_TO_URL_MAP_CONFIG_FILE
```

*PATH_TO_URL_MAP_CONFIG_FILE*: Replace with a path to the file that contains the URL map configuration for validation.

**Validating changes to an existing load balancer's URL map**

If you have an existing load balancer that needs changes to the URL map, you can test those configuration changes before making them live.

1. Export the load balancer's existing URL map to a YAML file.

```
gcloud compute url-maps export URL_MAP_NAME \
   --destination PATH_TO_URL_MAP_CONFIG_FILE \
   --global
```

2. Edit the YAML file with new configuration. For example, if you want to edit an external HTTP(S) load balancer and send all requests with the path `/video` to a new backend service called `video-backend-service`, you can add tests to the URL map configuration as follows:

Existing URL map configuration with a single default `web-backend-service`:

```
 kind: compute#urlMap
 name: URL_MAP_NAME
 defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendService/web-backend-service
```

Edited URL map configuration with added path matcher and tests for both the default `web-backend-service` and the new `video-backend-service` backend service:

```
 kind: compute#urlMap
 name: URL_MAP_NAME
 defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendService/web-backend-service
 hostRules:
 - hosts:
   - '*'
   pathMatcher: pathmap
 pathMatchers:
 - defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendService/web-backend-service
   name: pathmap
   pathRules:
   - paths:
     - /video
     - /video/*
     service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendService/video-backend-service
 tests:
 - description: Test routing to existing web service
   host: foobar
   path: /
   service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendService/web-backend-service
 - description: Test routing to new video service
   host: foobar
   path: /video
   service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendService/video-backend-service
```

3. Validate the new configuration.

```
gcloud compute url-maps validate --source PATH_TO_URL_MAP_CONFIG_FILE
```

If all tests pass successfully, you should see a success message such as:

```
Successfully validated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/urlMaps/URL_MAP_CONFIG_FILE_NAME
```

If the tests fail, an error message appears. Make the required fixes to the URL map config file and try validating again.

```
Error: Invalid value for field 'urlMap.tests': ''.
Test failure: Expect URL 'HOST/PATH' to map to service 'EXPECTED_BACKEND_SERVICE', but actually mapped to 'ACTUAL_BACKEND_SERVICE'.
```

4. Once you know that the new configuration works and does not impact your existing setup, you can import it into the URL map. Note that this step will also deploy the url map with the new configuration.

```
gcloud compute url-maps import URL_MAP_NAME \
   --source PATH_TO_URL_MAP_CONFIG_FILE \
   --global
```

**Important: If you originally set up your load balancer in the Cloud Console, the URL map name is the same as your load balancer's name.**